# Making a custom method that changes an objects property

Tags: javascript, methods, properties

I'm new to custom objects but have found them very useful, especially because the reduce a lot of code writing in the long run.

I'm working a particular algorithm that creates an clone element and uses a method that creates a new unique ID based on some properties of the cloned element. this is what it kinda looks like right now:

```
Element.prototype.theID = theID;

function theID(){
//this.makeNewID code
//code that builds a new ID and stores it in a variable called nwID
return nwID
}

function buildClone(cloneThis){
//builds  a clone out of the specified cloneThis element and stores it in a variable
//called clonedElement
 var nwID = clonedElement.theID;//determines a new ID
 clonedElement.setAttribute('id', nwID);//asignes the ID to the element.
 }
```

the last two lines in the buildClone() function is what I want to avoid. I would like the method to assign the new id to the specified element right in the method, rather then it just returning a new ID.

This is what I came up with

```
Element.prototype.theID = theID;

function theID(){
//this.makeNewID code
//code that builds a new ID and stores it in a variable called nwID
this.setAttribute('id', nwID);//asignes the ID to the element.
}

function buildClone(cloneThis){
//builds  a clone out of the specified cloneThis element and stores it in a variable
//called clonedElement
 clonedElement.theID();//determines a new ID
 }
```

This new way I attempted it doesn't work, I have also tried `return  clonedElement.theID;` and it doesn't seem to work. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

I apologize, It was an error in my part posting it on here, but I fixed it, this is what it actually looks like and It still doesn't work.

Comment: Shouldn't `var nwID = clonedElement.theID;` be `var nwID = clonedElement.theID();`?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it but it still doesn't work with the parenthesizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

theID is a function, so it needs to be called:

```
function buildClone(cloneThis){
    //builds  a clone out of the specified cloneThis element and stores it in a variable
    //called clonedElement
    clonedElement.theID(); //determines a new ID
}
```

Comment: Sorry, It did have the area for the parameters but it still didn't work.